# Two queries in FindOneAndUpdate don't work with arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema in Mongoose:

```
var CoinAmountSchema = new Schema(
{
    user: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    coinAmounts: [{
        _id: false,
        coinID: { type: Number, ref: 'Coin' },
        amount: Number
    }]
})
```

I am writing this query, that checks the userID and coinID and should update the amount of only that coinID's amount.

```
exports.coin_amount_update = [
(req, res, next) => {
    CoinAmount.update({
        "user": req.params.userId,
        "coinAmounts.coinID": req.params.coinId
    },
        {
            '$set': {
                'coinAmounts.$.amount': req.body.amount
            }
        },
        function (err, model) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return res.send(err)
            }
            return res.json(model)
        })
}]
```

But like this, it only updates the first coin's in the array amount. BUT, if I delete the line `"user": req.params.userId,` it would find and update the right coin. I need to check for a user as well though, so how can I make it work?
Is there something wrong with the query or the way the data is structured?

EDIT: I send a request in React-native:

```
fetch(`${apiBaseURL}/users/${getState().user._id}/coins/${id}/update`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            amount: getState().coins[id].amount
        }),
    })
```

If the request is /users/:userID/coins/0/update  (with amount: 1)
then the result will be

```
 { _id: 5a579d0d44e7390ba3029327,
  __v: 0,
  coinAmounts: 
   [ { coinID: 0, amount: 1 },
     { coinID: 1, amount: 0 },
     { coinID: 2, amount: 0 },
     { coinID: 3, amount: 0 },
     { coinID: 4, amount: 0 } ],
  user: [ 5a579d0d44e7390ba3029326 ] }
```

The same result if the request is /users/:userID/coins/1/update with the same amount.

But if as mentioned before, I remove the check for userID, the request /users/:userID/coins/1/update would produce this:

```
{ _id: 5a579d0d44e7390ba3029327,
      __v: 0,
      coinAmounts: 
       [ { coinID: 0, amount: 0 },
         { coinID: 1, amount: 1 },
         { coinID: 2, amount: 0 },
         { coinID: 3, amount: 0 },
         { coinID: 4, amount: 0 } ],
      user: [ 5a579d0d44e7390ba3029326 ] }
```

Hope I was clear.

Comment: what is your mongo db version ?

Comment: My mongodb version is 3.6.0

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. I've posted query at [mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mongodb-user/14ywNlu46DQ) group for someone to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug when using two arrays in `find` with `$` positional update, it gets matching index of `user` for `$` positional update

tried below workarounds, both updates correct coinID

workaround-1, using `arrayFilters`

```
db.coins.update(
    { "user" : "5a579d0d44e7390ba3029326" }, //user
    {
        $set: { "coinAmounts.$[elem].amount" : 1 } //update
    },
    { 
        multi: false,
        arrayFilters:   [
            {   "elem.coinID":  2 } //coinID
        ]
    }
)
```

workaround-2, using `elemMatch` for user array

```
db.coins.update(
    { 
        "coinAmounts.coinID" : 1, //coinID
        "user" : { $elemMatch : { $eq : "5a579d0d44e7390ba3029326" } } //user
    }, 
    { $set : { "coinAmounts.$.amount" : 1 } } //update
)
```